# Find duplicates of rounded geometries with mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following mongodb query which find objects by duplicated geometries within a collection:

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
        $match: { // Selection
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                geometry: "$geometry"
            }, 
            dups: {
                "$addToSet": "$_id"
            },
            count: {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: {
                "$gt": 1
            } // Duplicates considered as count greater than one
        }
    }
],
{ allowDiskUse: true }
```

I would like to change this query to find "similar" geometries, which means if the first n digit of the coordinates (so floored coordinates) are the same they should consider identical. All of my geometries are LineStrings.

Comment: *"... but I do not think it matters"* - Oh it most certainly **does**. matter. GeoJSON uses varying formats, mostly with different "ring" configurations of nested arrays. So the exact type of data you want to "extract these points" from is intrinsically important to the structure of the aggregation pipeline. There is no "generic" way to break apart either/or of `Polygon`, `MultiPolygon` or `LineString` since they are all basically **different** in structure. That's by-design

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm going to clarify the question then,